# Python PySVN - Branch revision history

Tags: python, branch, history, revision, pysvn

I'm using PySVN to access the SVN API from a python script.

I can't seem to find a way to figure out what other revision numbers there are in a given branch.

I can determine the revision number of my working copy trunk, as well as the revision number of the latest change by using info and/or info2, but I would like to find out what other revision numbers I have in the current branch (previous and later) so I will be able to update to other specific revisions.

Any ideas?

Thx, Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, I found a way: I can create a list of log messages using the log command and loop through those messages. They are dictionaries containing all relevant information..